# Missing Mapping Model after Adapting to another model

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, json-api, mapster

I have 2 service models and 2 DAL models. While creating new Author, I want to save its books to Book table. So, I send payload as json. However, If I try to adapt model to Book model, its values are null.So I can solve this problem. I also tried `model.Adapt<IEnumerable<Book>>()`, this also comes null.

```
public async Task<AuthorRequest> CreateAsync(AuthorRequest model)
{
    var authorEntity= model.Adapt<Author>(); // works fine
    var bookEntity =model.Adapt<Book>();//null
}
```

**Service.Models**

```
public class AuthorRequest :Identifiable<string>
{
    public string override Id{get;set;}

    [Attr("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Attr("surname")]
    public string Surname { get; set; }

    public  ICollection<BookRequest> Books{get; set; }
}

public class BookRequest :Identifiable<string>
{
    public string override Id{get;set;}
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

**DAL.Model**

```
public class Author : AuditableEntity
{
    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("surname")]
    public string Surname { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("books")]
    public Relationship<IList<Book>> Books;
}

public class Book :AuditableEntity
{
    [JsonProperty("Title")]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Author")]
    public Relationship<IList<Author>> Author;
}
```

**Mappings with mapster**

```
TypeAdapterConfig<DAL.Models.Author, Service.Models.AuthorRequest>.NewConfig();
TypeAdapterConfig<DAL.Models.Book, Service.Models.AuthorRequest>.NewConfig();
TypeAdapterConfig<DAL.Models.Book, Service.Models.BookRequest>.NewConfig();

TypeAdapterConfig<Service.Models.AuthorRequest, DAL.Models.Author>.NewConfig();
TypeAdapterConfig<Service.Models.AuthorRequest, DAL.Models.Book>.NewConfig();
TypeAdapterConfig<Service.Models.BookRequest, DAL.Models.Book>.NewConfig();
```

**AuthorRequest.JSON**

```
{
    "name": "William",
    "surname": "Shakespeare",
    "books": [{
        "title": "Macheth"
    }]
}
```

Comment: I don’t know Mapster, but why do you expect `model.Adapt<Book>()` to work here? If `model.Adapt<Author>()` maps to the author, then that works because the model looks like an `Author` object. But it only *contains* (possibly multiple) books, it *is* not a book, so it’s not surprising that it won’t map. Maybe you need to do something like `model.Books.Adapt<Book[]>()` here?

Answer (score 1):

Why do you expect `model.Adapt<Book>()` to yield any result here? Mapping entities usually works by copying over similar properties. This works for `AuthorRequest` and `Author` because they both contain the same properties. So when you map the `model`, which is an `AuthorRequest`, you properly get a filled `Author` object back.

However, when you try to map the same `AuthorRequest` to a (single) `Book` then that won’t work since they are just too different: `AuthorRequest` has the properties `Name`, `Surname`, and `Books`, while `Book` has the properties `Title` and `Author`. There is simply no match there.

What you can do is map the books that are *within* the `AuthorRequest` object, doing this:

```
var bookEntities = model.Books.Adapt<Book[]>();
```

This will not map the collection of `BookRequest` objects that are within the model to a `Book` array. This should work as expected.

Note though that Mapster is already smart enough to map nested types on its own. If you look at the `authorEntity` object, you will see that the nested book entities were *also* properly mapped. So if you want to map the `AuthorRequest` (which contains `BookRequest`s) to an `Author` entity containing `Book` entities, then your first line should already be enough:

```
var r = new AuthorRequest
{
    Name = "William",
    Surname = "Shakespeare",
    Books = new BookRequest[] {
        new BookRequest { Title = "Macbeth" },
        new BookRequest { Title = "Romeo and Juliet" },
    },
};
r.Adapt<Author>().Dump();
```

[image: Result of the previous code in LINQPad]

Comment: The reason to use model.Adapt<Book> is that I do not want to use foreach loop and do not want to create new instance of Book entity.  `model.Books.Adapt<Book[]>();` also does not work for me.

Comment: @beetlejuice Did you check that `model` actually contains your values? Did you look at the `authorEntity` object to see whether it already contains the book entities? Try my example and see if that works for you. Also check whether your `Relationship` type causes any problem there (I did it without that because I don’t know what it is); you might have to configure Mapster to recognize that.

Comment: Yes I check my `authorEntity`  and it contains Books' values. 
I have already done as you have shown in your example when the adapt method fails. I agree with you. It is related with mapster configuration.